# Combining columns from 2 pivot tables in order to make a chart

Tags: excel, pivot-table, pivot-chart

I am trying to combine 2 columns from a pivot table with 2 other columns from another pivot table so i can make a pivot chart. I have no clue how it is done. I can make a pivot chart for a single pivot table, but what should i do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

**You will most likely need to copy and paste the PivotTable data as values elsewhere.**

Once you generate a PivotChart, or even when you insert a generic chart and select values in the pivot table as the data source, the chart permanently becomes linked to the PivotTable, and *only* the PivotTable. In the `Select Data Source` dialog, the chart data range becomes frozen as does the Series and Category, because it's now determined by how your PivotTable is arranged.

When your data is not in a pivot table, you will have much more control over the chart. You can include columns and rows from anywhere, in any combination, and control that from the ribbon: Chart Tools > Design > Select Data. Turning that range into a table (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) will give you a few more features and better control over the range than plain cells.